# How can I have ajax call using backbone.js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

How can I write ajax calls using backbone.js, I read that sync is the key to ajax calls in backbone.js, but I am not able to understand it properly. It would be really helpful if it can be explained with an example.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I don't usually call `sync` by my own. We can say the `sync` is the *storage system connection*, `sync` by default use an *AJAX REST API* to persists and load the objects. `sync` is the method you have to *overwrite* if you want to use another *storage system*.

Instead of calling `sync` directly you use methods like `fetch`, `save`, `destroy`, ... wich ones will call `sync` internally.

In the documentation there are several examples:

- [Model.fetch](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch)
- [Model.save](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save)
- [Model.destroy](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-destroy)
- ..

and more for [Collection](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection)

The most simple example that comes to my mind can be how to load a *Book Model* from this url: `http://myapp.com/books/my_book.json`

```
# code simplified and not tested
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot = "http://myapp.com/books"
});

var myBook = new Book({ id: "my_book" });
myBook.fetch(); # => this is when the AJAX call is done, among other things
```

Comment: Gratitude fguillen... I am sorry to bother you again ,by any chance you have any link to a demo app implementing these functionality or tutorial regard to the above topic

Comment: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html is often cited as an example

Comment: [the TODO list Backbone demo app](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html), and a fast google shot has brought me to this [Backbone demo app](https://gist.github.com/1655019)